# How could I reset the state of my component according to changes in the parent component?

Tags: reactjs

In order to practice what I have learnt in React, I am trying to make some kind of a QCM in React.

[the architecture of the components of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QVne.png)

This image describe the architecture of the components of my application.

The App component contains the main states and the function to change the state.

The component Board contains the 4 proposed answers and some utilitaries functions to shuffle the answers it receives from the App component.

So the user can click on the button containing the answer. If the answer is wrong, the button becomes red. If the answer is correct, the button becomes green, the state of the App component changes to increase by 1 the number of correct answers. Also, thanks to another element of the state, the "button next" component is displayed. It allows to change the question and the answers. When the new answers appears, I would like the answers buttons to become in their initial color.

The issue is then : **how could i change the answer components' state with a click on the "button next" component ?**

So, I have stocked the color of the answer button in its state, and its update is done with an onClick event which calls a function in the App component.

I thought about changing the answer button color to its initial color when the count of good answers increases by one, but the result seems quite random.

When I search for answers on the web, I only find this kind of problem but with elements which are in the same react components and using the same state.

Does anyone have an idea ?

PS : for the moment, i try to do something without redux nor the hooks. I will use the hooks when I will succeed to do it with only basic react.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const datas = [
  {
    id:1,
    question: 1,
    answer: 11
  },
  {
    id:2,
    question: 2,
    answer: 22
  },
  {
    id:3,
    question: 3,
    answer: 33
  },
  {
    id:4,
    question: 4,
    answer: 44
  },
  {
    id:5,
    question: 5,
    answer: 55
  },
  {
    id:6,
    question: 6,
    answer: 66
  },
  {
    id:7,
    question: 7,
    answer: 77
  },
  {
    id:8,
    question: 8,
    answer: 88
  },
  {
    id:9,
    question: 9,
    answer: 99
  }
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      guesses: 0,
      won: false,
      buttonClicked: false
    }
  }

  getId(datas){
    const tabIdLetters = []
    datas.map((data, index) =>
      (tabIdLetters.push(data.id))
    )
    return tabIdLetters
  }  //return an array with the ID elements of the datas


  getRandom(arr, n) {
    var result = new Array(n),
        len = arr.length,
        taken = new Array(len);
    if (n > len)
        throw new RangeError("getRandom: more elements taken than available");

    while (n--) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        result[n] = arr[x in taken ? taken[x] : x];
        taken[x] = --len in taken ? taken[len] : len;
    }

    return result;
  } //get n random elements from a tab

  getOneRandom(arr) {
    var result,
        len = arr.length;
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        result = arr[x]
    return result;
  }  //get one random element from a tab

  handleWon(){
    this.setState({
      won: true
    })
  }

  handleButtonNext(){
    const newGuesses = this.state.guesses + 1
    this.setState({ 
      guesses: newGuesses,
      won: false,
      buttonClicked: true
    })
  }

  render(){
    const lettersSelected = this.getRandom(this.getId(this.props.datas), 4) //the 4 answers which will be displayed
    const letterQueried = this.getOneRandom(lettersSelected) //among these 4 letters, one will be the one being asked

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Board datas={datas} className="board" lettersSelected={lettersSelected} letterQueried={letterQueried} app={this} />
        <LetterQuerried lettersSelected={lettersSelected} letterQueried={letterQueried} app={this} />
        {this.state.won && <ButtonNext app={this} style={{display:this.state.visible}} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;

//============== component in which there are the 4 answers buttons ==================

class Board extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }    //shuffle the array to display the answer buttons in a random order

  //The component should re render only if the button next has been clicked
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(nextProps.app.state.buttonClicked == false){
      return false
    }
    else{
      return true
    }
  }

  render(){
    const datas = this.shuffle(this.props.datas)
    return(
      <div>
        {datas.map((data, index) => 
          (this.props.lettersSelected.includes(data.id) && <LetterProposed id={data.id} data={data.answer} key={index} letterQueried={this.props.letterQueried} app={this.props.app} board={this} />)
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//=========================== answer button component ===================================

class LetterProposed extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bgColor: 'gray'
    }
  }

  handlerClick(e){
    this.props.app.state.buttonClicked = false

    if(e.target.id == this.props.letterQueried){  //correct answer
      this.setState({
        bgColor: 'green'
      })
      this.props.app.handleWon()
    }
    else if(e.target.id != this.props.letterQueried){ //wrong answer
      this.setState({
        bgColor: 'red' 
      })
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(this.props.app.state.guesses !== nextProps.app.state.guesses){
      return false
    }
    else{
      return true
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <button id={this.props.id} onClick={this.handlerClick.bind(this)} style={{backgroundColor:this.state.bgColor}}>{this.props.data}</button>
    )
  }
}

//================= Question component ========================

class LetterQuerried extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(nextProps.app.state.buttonClicked == false){
      return false
    }
    else{
      return true
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <p>{this.props.letterQueried}</p>
    )
  }
}

//==================== Button next component ==============================

class ButtonNext extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      visible: 'block'
    }
  }

  handlerClick(){
    this.props.app.handleButtonNext()
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.handlerClick.bind(this)}>Suivant</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code of what you have tried so far. That would help to provide a clear and better solutions to your problems. Also see section on how to ask questions on the forum

Comment: @chitova263 I have edited my message to add the code.  I only hide the utilitaries functions to make it a little shorter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put child state to parent component and manage it there.

Or you can pass parent state to child  as a parameter.
And in child we apply this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {   
    if (this.props.parentStateFromProps !== prevProps.parentStateFromProps) {
    this.setState(INITIAL_STATE);
    }
}
```

with hooks:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(INITIAL_STATE);
}, [parentStateFromProps]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is still the same problem : when i click on the button to play again, not all the answers button turn back to their initial colour. And it is not always the same button who isn't at the initial colour. I don't really understand what is happening actually :(